# How to get a list of connected clients on SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am quite new to SignalR. 
My first assignment is to make simple chat app.

I have been browsing and reading and finally made a page where you come and chat and it works fine.

Now I need to show a list of connected clients. To achieve this I have wrote the following code.
This is my HUB.

```
public class ChatHub: Hub
{

    chatEntities dc = new chatEntities();
    public void Send(string message,string clientName)
    {
        Clients.addMessage(message,clientName);

    }

    // I want to save the user into my database, when they join 
    public void Joined(string userId,string userName)
    {

        CurrentChattingUsers cu = new CurrentChattingUsers();
        cu.ConnectionId = userId;
        cu.UserName = userName;

        dc.CurrentChattingUsers.AddObject(cu);
        dc.SaveChanges();


       Clients.joins(userId, userName);
    }

    // This will return a list of connected user from my db table.
    public List<ClientModel> GetConnectedUsers()
    {
        var query = (from k in dc.CurrentChattingUsers
                     select new ClientModel()
                     {
                         FullName = k.UserName,
                         UserId = k.ConnectionId
                     }).ToList();
        return query;
    }   


}
```

And thats it...Now what??
Am I going to the right direction? If, I am then how to call this methods from the view?
Some good suggestions will really help me out.
cheers

**EDIT:**

I have added the following script when the hub start

```
$.connection.hub.start(function () {
            chat.getConnectedUsers();

        });
```

This is the method that returns the client names in my Hub

```
  public List<ClientModel> GetConnectedUsers()
    {
        var data = (from k in dc.Users
                     select new ClientModel()
                     {
                         FullName = k.UserName

                     }).ToList();

         Clients.loadUsers(data);
        return data;
    }
```

in firebug i can see it returns something as follows;

```
{"State":{},"Result":[{"FullName":"mokarom","UserId":null},  {"FullName":"aka8000","UserId":null},{"FullName":"johnnyno5","UserId":null},{"FullName":"reza","UserId":null},{"FullName":"amyo","UserId":null},{"FullName":"rezatech","UserId":null}],"Id":"0","Error":null,"StackTrace":null}
```

But, how would I display that in my view??

**EDIT:**

this the complete view so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chat;
    var myClientName
    $(document).ready(function(){

      myClientName = '@Request.Cookies["ChatterName"].Value';


        // Created proxy
        chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Assign a function to be called by the server
        chat.addMessage = onAddMessage;

        // Register a function with the button click
        $("#broadcast").click(onBroadcast);


        $('#message').keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) { //Enter
                e.preventDefault();

                onBroadcast();

            }
        });

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
           chat.getConnectedUsers();

        });

        chat.loadUsers = function (data) {
            loadUsers(data); 

         };
    });


    function onAddMessage(message,clientName) {
        // Add the message to the list
        $('#messages').append('<div class="chatterName">' + clientName + ' </div><div class="chatterMessage"> ' + message + '</div><div class="clear">');

    }
    function onBroadcast() {
        // Call the chat method on the server
        chat.send($('#message').val(), myClientName);
        $('#message').val('');
    }
    function loadUsers(data) {
        $('#clientList').html(data.Result[0].FullName);

    }
</script>
```

Problem: don't see anything here:  $('#clientList').html(data.Result[0].FullName);
firebug says 'data is not defined'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
var chats = $.connection.chatHub;
chats.loadUsers = function (data) { loadUsers(data); };
var connectedUserCount = 0;

$.connection.hub.start(function () 
         { chats.getConnectedUsers(); });

function loadUsers =  = function (data) {
  console.log(data); //so you can see your data in firebug.etc
            //which signal r will have converted to json so you could try
  var numberOfUsers = data.length;  
}
```

Once hub is started chats would have all the public functions of your hub available as javascript functions.  This is what the signalr/hubs creates using the best available connection method between client and server.

In reverse your C# hub will have access to any javascripts functions you setup, e.g.

```
Clients.loadUsers(query);  
//add this to you server side just before you return query
```

ps - you might also consider using [OnConnectedAsync](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/178), though of course you might still persist these.  I'm also waiting for full support for web farm support using sql, which is in the [pipeline](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/232#issuecomment-8564220).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have tried exactly what you said.My Controller method returns '5'and I wrote this code to my view. $.connection.hub.start(function () {connectedUserCount = chat.getConnectedUsersCount();$('#clientList').append('<li>' + connectedUserCount + '</li>');});. . But it return something "[object Object]"...Any idea what may went wrong??

Comment: That object is your list.  See update to answer and maybe just try and start with sending back a simple poco or value back to the client for starters.  It does take a little to get the hang of the way this works.  (ps - my original answer had two flaws in it and may yet, as I'm pseudo writing this, not running it)

Comment: hope that begins to make sense, will look again in morning.

Comment: hi..thanks for the help..i will try those pretty soon and get back to you with what happens..

Comment: hi.edited the question, added some extra code that i wrote lately. but still can not get through. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17401/discussion-between-dove-and-kandroid)