# mvc signalr how to display all connected users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I need to build a chat using signalr and I am new in this.

So far I got only the chat by reading some others codes and tutorials and this is what I got:

on my ChatApp.Hubs I got the following code

```
public static class UserHandler
{
    public static HashSet<string> ConnectedIds = new HashSet<string>();
}
public class ChatHub : Hub
{

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

and my view I copy past from a tutorial

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}
<h2>Chat</h2>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion">
    </ul>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.--> 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page. 
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name) 
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
```

what I need now is to display all the connected users in the view
Appriciate your help
Thanks in advance

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660313/how-to-get-a-list-of-connected-clients-on-signalr) might be helpful

Comment: @user55 I read this post tried that and got stucked.      
Can you explain me what he did in this line:
`chatEntities dc = new chatEntities();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you pretty much either want to just store all 'Active' connections in some kind of database/storage or a static hashset/dictionary.

You save the `ConnectionIds` when the user connects and remove them when they disconnect :

### Hub

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
   static HashSet<string> CurrentConnections = new HashSet<string>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;
        CurrentConnections.Add(id);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        var connection = CurrentConnections.FirstOrDefault(x => x == Context.ConnectionId);

        if (connection != null)
        {
            CurrentConnections.Remove(connection);
        }

        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }


    //return list of all active connections
    public List<string> GetAllActiveConnections()
    {
        return CurrentConnections.ToList();
    }

}
```

### Client

I added a button and an unordered list.

### HTML

```html
<button id="show-all-connections">Show Connections</button>
<ul id="user-list">
</ul>
```

And added this javascript (using jQuery)

```
    $("#show-all-connections").on("click", function () {

        debugger;

        chatHub.server.getAllActiveConnections().done(function (connections) {
            $.map(connections, function (item) {
                $("#user-list").append("<li>Connection ID : " + item + "</li>");
            });
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps.

### Update

In your scenario, I don't see any hooks into using a custom UserId Provider or anything, so you're going to have to ask the User for a User Name and save the Connection ID with that.

### HTML

### JavaScript

```
        $("#add-connection").click(function () {
            var name = $("#user-name").val();
            if (name.length > 0) {
                chatHub.server.connect(name);
            }
            else {
                alert("Please enter your user name");
            }
        });
```

### Hub

```
    static List<Users> SignalRUsers = new List<Users>();

    public void Connect(string userName)
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;

        if (SignalRUsers .Count(x => x.ConnectionId == id) == 0)
        {
            SignalRUsers .Add(new Users{ ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName });
        }
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        var item = SignalRUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
        if (item != null)
        {
            SignalRUsers.Remove(item);
        }

        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }
```

### Users.cs

```
public class Users
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

This is psuedo code since I am not able to run this code at the moment. Hope it helps and gives you a clear enough direction.

Comment: C
It Helps, but the html respone is the connections
I need to display the users but insted it's displaying the connection
how can I return users insted?

Comment: How are you mapping users to connections? I only see you storing ConnectionIds

Comment: I am sorry, I just started signalr today and I am totally new in this, not sure what you mean by mapping the connections.

basically what I need is to display list of the active users,
btw any link to signalr tutorial will be appreciate

Comment: SignalR establishes a connection Id. You have the Option of mapping those connection Ids to users in a few different ways. How are you associating a user to a connection? A Dictionary/List/Database?

Comment: I didn't associate them, but actually I tried to add user name and connection id to database but I failed, sorry still training this

Comment: I'll update my example but I'm not going to use a database, I'm just going to use a dictionary and a custom class. That should sufficiently answer your question I think (while remaining on the SignalR topic)

Comment: Mark C thanks for the update, btw do I need to add Id key to class users?

Comment: The connection id?

Comment: It says there is no method like `Connect` on the server.

Comment: @CodeIt I recommend you post a question regarding a specific problem you're having rather than comment on this answer as it may not apply to you.

Comment: Thank you! I was using just a List and it was resetting each time the hub class was referenced or connected to

Comment: note that this implementation is not thread safe and can raise exception on CurrentConnections.Add(id)